# Linq - Left Outer Join - DataTables

Tags: vb.net, linq, left-join

I am wondering if anyone can help me. I am new to LINQ and still trying to understand how it fits together.

I have the following DataTables in memory:

```
currentDataTable    
previousDataTable
```

I want the LinQ query to return any transactions that exist in currentDataTable that do not exist in previousDataTable.

A SQL example below:

```
SELECT Table1.*
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.DealReference = Table2.DealReference
WHERE (((Table2.DealReference) Is Null));
```

Can someone please guide me, how to achieve the same in LinQ.

Thanks

BM

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim result = From c In currentDataTable    
             Group Join p In previousDataTable
             On c.Field(Of String)("DealReference") Equals p.Field(Of String)("DealReference")
             Into DataGroup = Group
             From row In DataGroup.DefaultIfEmpty
             Where row Is Nothing AndAlso c.Field(of String)("Counterparty") <> "*"
             Select c
```

Comment: The last field in the "Counterparty" column contains a "*" character to denote the end of the file.  Do I need to do a new query to filter this out before the Left Join or can this be added into the above query?

Comment: I'm afraid i cannot follow. What is the `CounterParty` column? If it's a string field, why does that matter for your query? How can a column contain a _"last field"_? Normally the term "field" is a synonym of "column".

Comment: Sorry Tim, Its the waya the DataTable is structured.  The last row of the CurrentDataTable contains a "*" in the Counterparty column.  The DealReference of this row is blank.  It is not finding a corresponding deal on the PreviousDealsTable so comes back on the LinQ query.  Is there anyway to ommit deals where Counterparty equals "*" and transaction does not exist on previous deals?  If not, i'll just do a seperate query where Counterparty <> "*"